# Buscar dados entre um período em uma tabela com campos data inicio e data fim

Tags: sql, data

Estou com um problema para buscar dados em uma tabela com campos data inicio e data fim entre um período (um filtro de - até)

Os dados de exemplo são:

```
ID - INICIO     - FIM
1  - 01/01/2017 - 31/12/2017
2  - 10/01/2017 - 01/02/2017
3  - 01/05/2017 - 01/06/2017
4  - 15/05/2017 - 15/06/2017
5  - 01/09/2017 - 31/10/2017
```

Dai tenho 3 buscas e com retornos esperados

> 1ª busca entre 01/01/2017 - 31/12/2017
> retorno esperado - 1-2-3-4-5
>
> 2ª busca entre 01/04/2017 - 30/06/2017
> retorno esperado - 1-3-4
>
> 3ª busca entre 02/06/2017 - 02/07/2017
> retorno esperado - 1-4

A query que fiz para primeira busca foi:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ba8d19/2

```
select * from dados
where
    dt_inicio >= '2017-01-01' AND dt_inicio <= '2017-12-31'
AND dt_fim >= '2017-01-01' AND dt_fim <= '2017-12-31'
// o resultado foi ok
```

A query que fiz para segunda busca foi:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ba8d19/3

```
select * from dados
where
    dt_inicio >= '2017-04-01' AND dt_inicio <= '2017-06-30'
AND dt_fim >= '2017-04-01' AND dt_fim <= '2017-06-30'
// o resultado FALHOU
```

A query que fiz para terceira busca foi:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ba8d19/4

```
select * from dados
where
    dt_inicio >= '2017-06-02' AND dt_inicio <= '2017-07-02'
AND dt_fim >= '2017-06-02' AND dt_fim <= '2017-07-02'
// o resultado FALHOU
```

Segue script para criar a tabela e os dados:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `dados` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `dt_inicio` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
  `dt_fim` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00'
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


INSERT INTO `dados` (`id`, `dt_inicio`, `dt_fim`) VALUES
(1, '2017-01-01', '2017-12-31'),
(2, '2017-01-10', '2017-02-01'),
(3, '2017-05-01', '2017-06-01'),
(4, '2017-05-15', '2017-06-15'),
(5, '2017-01-09', '2017-10-31')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depois de uma discussão em outros grupos, consegui uma solução, segue:

```
SELECT * FROM dados
WHERE 
    dt_inicio <= '$dt_fim_busca'
AND dt_fim >= '$dt_inicio_busca'
```

Com os exemplos passados para `$dt_inicio_busca` e `$dt_fim_busca`

```
$dt_inicio_busca | $dt_fim_busca
--------------------------------
01/01/2017       | 31/12/2017
01/04/2017       | 30/06/2017
02/06/2017       | 02/07/2017
```